# Filtering an active record relation

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an Availabilities class

```
class Availability < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Associations
  belongs_to :facility
  has_one :venue, through: :facility
end
```

In that class I have a search method which I call like this in my controller:

`@search = Availability.search(params, get_location)`

```
  def self.search(params, location)
    perform_search(location, params[:activity], params[:start_time], params[:end_time],params[:period])
  end

  def self.perform_search(location, activity, start_time, end_time, period)
    self
      .not_booked
      .after_now
      .close_to(Venue.close_to(location))
      .activity(Activity.find_by_name activity)
      .start_date(validate_start_time start_time)
      .end_date(validate_end_time end_time)
      .within_segment_of_day(period)
      .sorted
  end
```

**Problem:** I now need to add an additional filter. Each venue has it's own minimum time (`notice_time:integer type`) before an availability can be booked.

> For example: You can only book an availability as long as we have 48
>   hour notice from the start time

I tried to accomplish this by adding a new scope:

```
scope :after_notice_time, -> {joins{venue}.where{start_time >= (venue.notice_time.hours.from_now)}}
```

But got **error**:

> [58] pry(main)> Availability.after_notice_time
>   Availability Load (4.9ms)  SELECT "availabilities".* FROM "availabilities" INNER JOIN
>   "facilities" ON "facilities"."id" = "availabilities"."facility_id"
>   INNER JOIN "venues" ON "venues"."id" = "facilities"."venue_id" WHERE
>   "availabilities"."start_time" >= "hours"."from_now"
>
> PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table
>   "hours" LINE 1: ..."venue_id" WHERE "availabilities"."start_time" >=
>   "hours"."f...
>                                                                ^ : SELECT "availabilities".* FROM "availabilities" INNER JOIN
>   "facilities" ON "facilities"."id" = "availabilities"."facility_id"
>   INNER JOIN "venues" ON "venues"."id" = "facilities"."venue_id" WHERE
>   "availabilities"."start_time" >= "hours"."from_now"
>   => # < Availability::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x5b525ac>

How do I filter the results so that I can check each availabilities `venue.notice_time` and make sure that my final `@search` only includes availabilities where their start_time is greater than `current time + notice time`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this with plain SQL (this code is PG specific):

```
scope :after_notice_time, 
-> { joins(:venue)
.where("start_time >= (current_timestamp + venues.notice_time * interval '1 hour') }
```

Comment: Someone on Reddit gave me this solution which is pretty much identical to yours: `joins(:venue).where("start_time >= now() + venues.notice_time * '1 hour'::interval") ` It seems to be working perfectly